# Using Assertions in code not just in tests

Tags: junit, assertion

I understand, Assertions are used in tests to check if the programmer's pre- and post- conditions are true and if the assertions fail, there is/are bug/bugs that need to debugged and fixed.

An assertion is a software construct where the developer states ("asserts") a condition that he believes will always be true. If the condition evaluates to false in some languages an exception is thrown, **in others a message is printed**, and in others the program ceases to operate.

"A message is printed" highlighted in the above definition caught my attention.

My question is, can we extend the use of assert statements in the actual code itself and catch AssertionErrors to log the messages and not just tests? 
Basically to avoid too much verbose with if-else statements(I hate if-else btw, personally). 
For example, all of below

```
String response = aMethod(sendSomething);
if (response!=null && response!="") {
  //blah blah
} else { 
  log.error("Response is null");
  throw new NoDataFoundException();
}
```

could be replaced with the below that provides more detailed messages.

```
try{
   assertThat(aMethod(sendSomething), notNullValue());
} catch (AssertionError e) {
   log.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Interesting related article: 
http://news.kynosarges.org/2017/06/07/catching-java-assertion-errors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to catch an assertion failure(*).  By definition, the program is operating outside its design perimeter. The only safe thing to do is get out.

(*) OK, you can catch it if the point of catching it is to log whatever you anticipating you'll need to diagnose the problem, and then get out quickly.

In your example, it appears that after testing for a response and logging the failure, you'll carry on inline. In general, that would be a bad idea, but perhaps this was just a quick illustration on your part and should not be taken too literally.

As to what I take to be your overall point: yes, if you're checking pre/postconditions at all, leave the checks in shipping code.

My code would look like:

```
  response = aMethod(sendSomething);
  if (response == null || response.isEmpty())
     throw new InternalError("....");
```

and there would be something catching the error at some outermost layer, a point of exception handling being that you can transfer control far away rather than having to deal with everything at the point it occurs -- especially if "it can't happen".

Comment: Agree with all your comments. I understand whatever I'm suggesting above needs to be used with caution, if at all it is used that way.  And you are right about my example, it is just that, quick illustration. Just to elaborate, if I receive a null response say from a REST API call , or some part of the response was null, I cannot continue further and will hault further processing.  So, trying to leverage some of the frameworks like hamcrest that provide detailed messages without making the code verbose.

Comment: Actually, you don't *need* to test for null, you can just go ahead and use he result as if it were not null.Then you'll get a null pointer exception, which the aforementioned last-chance 'catch' will handle.  Dump the callback stack into wherever the problem will be logged.

Comment: My preference in all this is to not use in production code what is essentially intended as a test framework. I prefer explicit checking of values, it seems straightforward to me.  Its verbosity can be controlled; often a simple ```if (x) throw y``` is all you need.  No need for ```else``` after a ```throw```.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.